# How to simply pass stored items from one activity to another to then process

Tags: java, android, ocr, android-camera2

Hi Just starting with java and I have to working activitys which I now want to combine.

### activity1

```
    private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    /**
     * The JPEG image
     */
    private final Image mImage;
    /**
     * The file we save the image into.
     */
    private final File mFile;

    ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;

    }
```

and I want the mImage to be availbe in activity2

### activity2

```
public class activity2 {}
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: write get() and set() methods for mImage and mFile and create object of class ImageSaver in activity2  class and by using getImage() method you will get mImage .

Answer (score 0):

One easy and efficient way to do that is to use any of the image caching libraries out there, just as example, [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)

If you image is loaded in the first activity, requesting the same image with the same URL, will make the library load it from cache instead of loading it again from network.

You can pass a URI object to these libraries which can be a URL or a file path

I would advice against sending images through Intent's Bundle, because they will slow down your activity start, and also might throw an exception on Android's latest versions.